# How to add another row in Best Seller items in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'll like to add another row of 4 best items on my home page under "LOS MAS VENDIDOS", how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Back office->Modules->Modules
Search Top Sellers Block
Add number of products in the text box and save. I did this on prestashop 1.6.0.6 and it works for me.
[image]